# Subversion post-commit hooks access is denied

Tags: svn, nant, svn-hooks

My system is Windows2008 R2 64bit, and i install VisutalSubversion Server. The post-commit.bat as the follow statement:

```
C:\nant\bin\nant -buildfile:C:\Repositories\xxx\hooks\xxx.build
```

When i commit file from client, it throw the errors

**post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
Access is denied.**

But the post-commit.bat file can be run without errors when i manually clicked.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read somewhere that the issue could be resolved by:

1. Right click the svn.exe and click run as administrator.
2. Change the VisualSVN Server service to "log on as Local system account".

I haven't tested it myself though.

Comment: Thanks, i used step 1 to set the svn.exe and click run as administrator...And it works,,thanks very much!

Comment: Change the VisualSVN Server service to "log on as Local system account" worked for me